# Javascript call and apply on constructor functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, call, apply

I understand how call (and apply) method works in the following example.

```
var Bob = {
  name: "Bob",
  greet: function() {
   alert("Hi, I'm " + this.name);
  }
}

var Alice = {
 name: "Alice",
};

Bob.greet.call(Alice);   // Hi, I'm Alice
```

From what I understand, what's happening above is he greet method of Bob object is invoked with the scope of Alice.

Can someone explain what is happening behind the scenes in the below example, where the call method is used on a constructor function which allows inheritance?

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

var chicken = new Food('chicken','40');
console.log(chicken);  //{ name= "chicken", price="40", category="food"}
```

I can't make the connection between the first and second example, where the first example the call method is invoked on a function that is doing something (alert), whereas in the second example, the call method is used on a constructor function that is initializing some properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way of "borrowing" the constructor function of `Product` to initialize your new `Food`.

When you call a function with `new`, you're setting `this` to be the new instance. You're then doing `Product.call` (i.e. calling the `Product` function and setting `this` inside the `Product` function to be your new `Food` instance (which is `this` inside `Food`)), and passing your `name` and `price`.

After `Product.call(this, name, price);` you should find that `this.name` and `this.price` have been set.

This doesn't allow inheritance, nor do you *gain* inheritance; it just executes the constructor function `Product` on your new `Food` instance.

To gain inheritance, you'd also have to set the `prototype` of `Food` to be a new `Product` instance;

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

Product.prototype.showPriceIn = function (currency) {
    alert(this.price + currency);
} 

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

Food.prototype = new Product;

var chicken = new Food('chicken','40');
chicken.showPriceIn("$");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hPWMN/

---

**N.B:** Be careful saying that "Bob is invoked with the ***scope*** of Alice"; this isn't true. Bob doesn't inherit the scope of Alice, the value of `this` inside the `greet` function is merely altered to be `Alice`. Inheriting the scope would imply Bob gains access to private variables and the like, which he doesn't.

Comment: I think the main part I don't understand is that when you are calling the Product function inside Food, how does the calling of that function give 'this' of Food the 'name' and 'price' property.  Can you explain this part in particular?

Comment: @eirikrl: Because the first parameter to `apply()` and `call()` defines what the `this` should be inside the function, right? Inside the `Food` constructor, we're passing `this`, which is the new `Food` instance we've constructed (which you can see as `this.category` is being set to "food"). Therefore, everytime you do `this.something = something` inside `Product` after it has been `call`'d from `Food` the *this* is now the `Food` instance (like it was for `this.category = "food"`).

Comment: ... hope that makes more sense? Maybe the N.B at the bottom of my post will help as well? All `call()` and `apply()` does is call the function, but set the value of `this` to whatever you specify.

Comment: Nevermind I got it - thanks for the explanation!  Marked as best answer.

Comment: your ```Food.prototype = new Product;``` line is not really right, as it's running the constructor at definition time.  A better solution (in modern browsers) is ```Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);```.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain with simple example, here it is

```
function Human(name,surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

Human.prototype.method = function(){
    alert("Hi " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
};

var obj = new Human("Name","Surname");
obj.method();
```

In this case `Human` is constructor in which you are defining properties name and surname.
`prototype` function makes extending with `method` function where I'm using `this` key. It refers to specified objects , which are defined from outside.

With `var obj = new Human("Name","Surname");` you are initializing `Human` class and passing there values (name,surname). In this case you have one object named `obj` , but you can defined as many you like